# how to display highchart graphic with data defined in html table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I think I've done the right steps to create a highchart with data defined in the html table. but when I'm going to run it, only the table shown, the graph can't displayed. my table data load from database. there might be parts that I miss this is my code:

```js
var chart1; // globally available
 $(document).ready(function() {
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'grafik',
            type: 'column'
        },
        data: {
            table: document.getElementById('aruskas')
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="aruskas" class="table table-condensed" style="margin-left: 10px;">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="100px"></th>
      <th width="100px">Pemasukan</th>
      <th width="100px">Pengeluaran</th>
    </thead>

    <?php
    include '../koneksi.php';

    $sql   = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tgl, '%m') as tanggal FROM penjualan WHERE year(tgl)='2016' UNION (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%m') as tanggal FROM pembelian WHERE year(tanggal)='2016') ORDER BY tanggal ASC";
      $query = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql)  or die(mysqli_error());
      while( $ret = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ){
        $tgl=$ret['tanggal'];

      /*menghitung pemasukan*/
      $sql_jumlah   = "SELECT sum(total_harga) FROM penjualan where year(tgl)='2016' AND month(tgl)='$tgl' ";        
      $query_jumlah = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql_jumlah) or die(mysqli_error());
      while( $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_jumlah) ){
       $jumlah = $data['sum(total_harga)'];                 
     }
     $sql_jumlah1   = "SELECT sum(total) FROM aruskas where year(tgl)='2016' AND month(tgl)='$tgl' and noref like '%CI%' ";        
     $query_jumlah1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql_jumlah1) or die(mysqli_error());
     while( $data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_jumlah1) ){
       $jumlah1 = $data1['sum(total)'];                 
     }
     $pemasukan = $jumlah+$jumlah1;

     /*menghitung pengeluaran*/
     $sql_jumlah   = "SELECT sum(total_harga) FROM pembelian where year(tanggal)='2016' AND month(tanggal)='$tgl'  ";        
     $query_jumlah = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql_jumlah) or die(mysqli_error());
     while( $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_jumlah) ){
       $jumlah = $data['sum(total_harga)'];                 
     }
     $sql_jumlah1   = "SELECT sum(total) FROM aruskas where year(tgl)='2016' AND month(tgl)='$tgl' and noref like '%CT%' ";        
     $query_jumlah1 = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql_jumlah1) or die(mysqli_error());
     while( $data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_jumlah1) ){
       $jumlah1 = $data1['sum(total)'];                 
     }
     $pengeluaran = $jumlah+$jumlah1;
  
     ?>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <?php if ($tgl==01) {
        echo "Januari";
      }elseif ($tgl==02) {
        echo "Februari";
      }elseif ($tgl==03) {
        echo "Maret";
      }elseif ($tgl==04) {
        echo "April";
      }elseif ($tgl==05) {
        echo "Mei";
      }elseif ($tgl==06) {
        echo "Juni";
      }elseif ($tgl==07) {
        echo "Juli";
      }elseif ($tgl==8) {
        echo "Agustus";
      }elseif ($tgl==9) {
        echo "September";
      }elseif ($tgl==10) {
        echo "Oktober";
      }elseif ($tgl==11) {
        echo "November";
      }elseif ($tgl==12) {
        echo "Desember";
      }else{

      } ?>
        </th>
        <td><?php echo $pemasukan; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pengeluaran; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>


  </table>

  <div id="grafik"></div>

  <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you include the JS code in your php file? please include that part in your example

Comment: I have not worked with highcharts, but with other JS classes you also need to call a method to actually draw the chart. something like chart1.plot().

Comment: i've put JS code below the table code. I think using id to display the graph it can be done.  i have not used plot() before, how to use plot() in JS? @ErikKalkoken

Comment: Can you paste the web source here (only js + html code without php)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I it figured out: The main reason why the graph is not showing is that you did not include the data JS file.

Add this line to your php file below the other JS includes:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
```

You are also missing a closing `</tr>` in the table header.

Here is a working solution in a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Erik_Kalkoken/4hhnL3d7/). (without the PHP code)

Allow me make a suggestion on how to improve the structure of your code and make it easier to read and debug:

I would first gather all data from the database and store it in an array. And then (in a separate loop) create the table by using the data from that array.

Comment: i have try this, but still not display :(

Comment: I added a new solution, please check it out